# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.'

Tags: c#

I'm building a script that downloads a file from a URL and then executes it, but for some reason when I debug the script, it throws an error like:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'An error occurred trying to start process "" with working directory "". The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.'

Here is my code:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
String myUserName = Environment.UserName;
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var responseStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync("http://exampleurl.com/examplefile.exe");
using var fileStream = new FileStream("C:/Users/"+myUserName+"/examplefile.exe", FileMode.Create);
responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); // sleeping waiting until download completes
string str = @"C:/Users/"+myUserName+"/examplefile.exe";
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = str;
process.Start();
```

Comment: 1. your error message is pretty clear and straightforward. (try disposing your fileStream before doing anything else with the file) 2. please ***do not!*** execute a file you've just downloaded. there's very little reason to do things like this, except with malevolent intent.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann - Although it's obvious to those experienced with the error, the fact that the error message blames "another process" when, more often than not, it's your own process means that I don't consider that particular error to be clear.

Comment: *sleeping waiting until download completes* - I don't think C# needs a bit of extra time, after a syncronous CopyTo returns, to "finish off"..

Answer (score 0):

Had to add **fileStream.Close()** after the file download.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Using the below helped me solve the issue:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = _PathSave, UseShellExecute = true });
```